# Wget cannot resolve host downloading https

Tags: linux, https, download, wget

I have to write a script to download https://wordpress.org/latest.zip

Therefore I am using the wget command.

The problem is, that it does not work with any https:// url ..

for example:

```
wget http://google.de is working 

wget https://google.de is not working
```

trying to download a https:// url there is always the error:

```
wget: cannot resolve host address
```

Does anybody know what i should do?

Thanks

Comment: Working fine for me. Try with `https://google.com` ?

Comment: Same as google.de 
the error is:
Cannot resolve host address >>google.com (google.com)<< Name or Client is not known

Comment: What does `dig +short wordpress.org` return? Are you behind a proxy? Try `wget --no-proxy https://wordpress.org/latest.zip`

Comment: related: [WGET can't resolve host](http://serverfault.com/q/76421/3933)

Comment: the first one returns nothing and the second one returns the same as everytime: "wget: cannot resolve host >>wordpress.org (wordpress.org)<<

Comment: It seems it is a dns issue. What do you get with `dig @8.8.8.8 +short wordpress.org`?

Comment: ;; invalid option
<<>>DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 + short wordpress.org
; (1 server found)
;;global options +cmd
;;connection timed out; no servers could be reached
;;connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

wget --no-check-certificate https://google.de